# Can i use javascript in C#.Net Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I want to know if I can use JavaScript in C#.Net Windows Form. If it can be used, how can I use that JavaScript.

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 2):

No, javascript is a client scripting engine based on the Document Object Model (DOM) elements within a browser.

You list c# against this post, I'd suggest that you should invest some time learning LINQ for .net as this provides a DOM like query syntax for your windows forms. In fact, you can then query any .Net classes / objects.

Here's a link to the LINQ 101 examples;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: Javascript is not a client scripting engine. It is primarily used as one, but it doesn't care if there's DOM around or not.

Comment: @GSerg: True, however I was trying to simplify things a little for the original poster who's clearly confused about client / server side languages. +1

Comment: Well, C#, when referred to in context of Windows.Forms, is a client-side language, too. So the question starts making sense after all. There are desktop apps out there written in JavaScript.

Comment: What does LINQ have to do with JavaScript again?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Javascript.NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net).

However, please make sure you are not trying to use javascript to solve a task much more easily solved with a more mainstream parts of the framework/c# language.

Answer (score 1):

No.  JavaScript needs a runtime environment.  Such a runtime environment is present in browser, but not in Windows Forms.

In Windows Forms, you can use all the features of C# or any other programming language on the .NET platform. Hence, there is no need for a cross-browser, cross-platform language like JavaScript.

If you have an existing web application which have some functionality you would like to reuse, you *could* show it in browser frame within your Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can write/use an existing framework that handles this for you, and write some bindings to your UI or something. I've used http://jurassic.codeplex.com/ in the past, and its proven very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful:

```
  object result = this.Browser.InvokeScript("showOverlay", false);
```

For the full example:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/sep/27/calling-javascript-functions-in-the-web-browser-control